# Assigning MailItem.HTMLBody make images of lesser quality

Tags: vba, outlook

I use VBA to create a MailItem in Outlook. A signature is configured, so the Display makes sure that it is visible. All ok. But anything I do to the body after that, causes images in the signature to be rasterized to a lower color depth, or sized wrong. Even with this simple code, changing nothing, the signature gets garbled:

```
    Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    MailOutLook.Display
    MailOutLook.HTMLBody = MailOutLook.HTMLBody
```

Interestingly enough after assigning the HTMLBody to itself the contents differs from before. New styles were added, existing ones changed (e.g span.EmailStyle17 was changed and the original became span.EmailStyle18), the img block appears the same, but the image itself is now rendered with dithering.

In the end my question is: how do I insert some text in the HTMLBody without ruining it?

Comment: Can you make sure the body format property is set to `olFormatHTML`? If it's set to `olFormatRichText`, `MailOutLook.HTMLBody = MailOutLook.HTMLBody` takes the mail HTML, converts it to RTF, and then converts it back to HTML because Outlook always uses HTML internally. That could explain your issue.

Comment: It is, printed it out: MailOutLook.BodyFormat=2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the image-problem was caused by a poorly defined signature HTML (a.o. the img had no height and width attributes). That may explain why Outlook feels the need to modify the HTML, but IMHO it should not touch what I tell it to render.